# Creating a list of class from a class name

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have to create a list, but i only know the class name

```
public void getList(string className)
{

 IList lsPersons = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(className))));

}
```

I tried so many methods but nothing works for me.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid description. We cannot help you when it "does not work". Tell us what you tried and what failed. with specific error messages.

Comment: you should also mention what values you are using for `className`

Comment: This code works for me if `className` is `System.Int32`, so your `className` may be the problem.

Comment: @Knaģis it's a class name like Employee class

Comment: @JohnSaunders we are trying to generalize some of our current codes, so for that we have to pass a class from the .aspx page and we are accepting it in the code behind through jquery ajax method. so if we can create a method that can create an object of the same class and make it to a list that will reduce our half work –

Comment: I question your use case. Once you have an empty list of a given type, it is then necessary to fill that list. Surely, the code that fills the list knows the full type of the list (or should know).

Comment: @JohnSaunders   Type tableType=Type.GetType(ClassName); foreach(PropertyInfo pinfo in tableType.GetProperties())
            {
             arrList.Add(pinfo.Name);
            }   //will give me the properties name right?

Comment: Sounds over-general. Adding complexity to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a generic list but it is not useful. If you want to have a generic `List<T>` , somewhere you **SHOULD** incorporate your prior knowledge about the demanded type. For example you can do something like this:

```
if(className == "Employee") // this is where your prior knowledge is playing role
{ 
    IList<Employee> lsPersons = (IList<Employee>)Activator.CreateInstance(
             typeof(List<Employee>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(className))));
}
```

Also, you can make a generic list of any type via something like this:

```
public static class GenericListBuilder
{
    public static object Build(Type type)
    {
       var obj = typeof(GenericListBuilder)
                .GetMethod("MakeGenList", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type })
                .Invoke(null, (new object[] {}));
       return obj;
    }

    private static List<T> MakeGenList<T>()
    {
       return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

And it is possible to consume it like:

```
var List<Employee> = GenericListBuilder.Build(typeof(Employee)) as List<Employee>;
```

or

```
IList list = GenericListBuilder.Build(Type.GetType(className)) as IList;
```

The last line is completely blind and I think it is very close to what you have in mind. But does it have any benefit? I don't think.